# Save file/open file dialog box, using Swing & Netbeans GUI editor

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, user-interface

I am a beginner to Java. I am making a simple text editor in netbeans 7(.3) IDE, using its GUI editor. The main problem I face in it is that I can't make it to save/open the file. I have created the "save" button. When I drop the file chooser, it comes as a normal open file dialog box embedded in the java window with no functionality at all. I have also tried creating a new jFileChooser when the save button is clicked (in the Source view), but it doesn't work.

In a nutshell, I need a simple open/save dialog box. When the "Save" button is pressed, the save dialog box opens and saves the file wherever the user chooses with whatever name and .rtf  or .txt extension. (P.S.: is it possible to save a file in .docx or .doc in Java?)
When the "Open" btn is pressed, it opens a file in .rtf or .txt (again, is it possible to open .docx or .doc in Java?) through the file chooser.

```
    private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
    if saveFile.showSaveDialog(modalToComponent) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION {
        File xyz = saveFile.getSelectedFile();
    }
}
```

Code is here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B766zz1iJ1LRN2lGRjNtM29vN2M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: post some code please

Comment: we need to see some code

Comment: yeah, that code didn't help at all, as it's full with html tags..

Comment: @Aboutblank code added

Comment: @Maciej Cygan code added

Comment: please post an excerpt of the code here using code blocks (looks like {}). no one needs/wants to read all your code (your link doesn't even work). http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Aboutblank I guess your net isn't working properly. It opens totally fine here. And what should I paste here if you don't want all the code?

Comment: please read the link I posted.

Comment: @PratikAnand you should also read the FAQ.  This question should be self contained as Aboutblank says, and the specific code you wrote that doesn't open a file dialog is the only relevant part of the code.

Comment: Also your request is already covered by the Swing File Chooser demo isn't it?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#JWSFileChooserDemo

Comment: To answer your actual question, you can save a file from java with any extension you want.  It's up to you to make sure that the contents of the file match the extension.  In other words, if you write a note.doc file, the file should contain a Word document in the 1997 Word document format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have created a sample UI which shows the save and open file dialog. Click on save button to open save dialog and click on open button to open file dialog.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class FileChooserEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FileChooserEx().createUI();
            }
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }

    private void createUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton saveBtn = new JButton("Save");
        JButton openBtn = new JButton("Open");

        saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
                saveFile.showSaveDialog(null);
            }
        });

        openBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser();
                openFile.showOpenDialog(null);
            }
        });

        frame.add(new JLabel("File Chooser"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(saveBtn, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(openBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setTitle("File Chooser");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean the digalog box style on windows operation system as this code makes a digalog box like the one on Mac.

Comment: @Amarnath, what file are you saving with the save button? How do I tell the  `ActionListener` to open the dialog saving a specific file? Can I specify to `JFileChooser` a default folder to open? Thanks in advance for your time and congratulations for your answer

Answer (score 3):

I think you face three problems:

1. understanding the FileChooser
2. writing/reading files
3. understanding extensions and file formats

ad 1. Are you sure you've connected the FileChooser to a correct panel/container? I'd go for a simple tutorial on this matter and see if it works. That's the best way to learn - by making small but large enough steps forward. Breaking down an issue into such parts might be tricky sometimes ;)

ad. 2. After you save or open the file you should have methods to write or read the file. And again there are pretty neat examples on this matter and it's easy to understand topic.

ad. 3. There's a difference between a file having extension and file format. You can change the format of any file to anything you want but that doesn't affect it's contents. It might just render the file unreadable for the application associated with such extension. TXT files are easy - you read what you write. XLS, DOCX etc. require more work and usually framework is the best way to tackle these.

Answer (score 2):

saving in any format is very much possible.
Check following-
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

2ndly , What exactly you are expecting the save dialog to work , it works like that,
Opening a doc file is very much possible-
http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/openworddoc.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
private void doOpenFile() {
    int result = myFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        Path path = myFileChooser.getSelectedFile().toPath();

        try {
            String contentString = "";

            for (String s : Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                contentString += s;
            }

            jText.setText(contentString);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void doSaveFile() {
    int result = myFileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);

    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        // We'll be making a mytmp.txt file, write in there, then move it to
        // the selected
        // file. This takes care of clearing that file, should there be
        // content in it.
        File targetFile = myFileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            if (!targetFile.exists()) {
                targetFile.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(targetFile);

            fw.write(jText.getText());
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```